# Is this possible to filter own / non-own keys in a mapped type?

Tags: typescript

This question is a follow-up of my previous question: [«How to get all the properties (but not methods) from a class instance?»](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74320960/how-to-get-all-the-properties-but-not-methods-from-a-class-instance/74321141#74321141).

The acceptable answer of that question was this type:

```js
type Newable = { new(...args: readonly unknown[]): unknown }
type AnyFn = (...args: unknown[]) => unknown

type ClassProperties<C extends Newable> = {
  [
    K in keyof InstanceType<C>
      as InstanceType<C>[K] extends AnyFn
        ? never
        : K
  ]: InstanceType<C>[K]
}
```

It was technically correct and solve my original task, but I'm curious is it possible **to not rely** whether there isn't any instance properties with a function type (e.g. some callbacks passed in the constructor and stored in instance properties)? What if I want not «filter out properties which have a function type», but «filter out properties which is not own»? Is it possible?

Thank you.

**UPD**: I've created a minimal meaningful [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxgNghgzjAEAxA9sgRlATvA3qeB8ADgK5oQCWY8mAplACbIB2EAnvAG5QQm3wBeeAEYA3PkKlyVGvSasOYHhAxgA1oPgAKAJSCAfLgC%204kBIJTK1JrtzwjoB2ZDwA9K-gAVAPIARbwBc8AAuABYUCBEhofwAjnwwwRQsoMFsRPwAwtBwAAqYyBmYSbQwADyZ8LQAHsG0zAwIzLQA7loAdJ1YAOYwQXSMLOzwJMxqzMgtzADaALp6Aoaj45PMhkLoAFa0YMGgoGAsifAAZqgY2ELNLUjnWLoHR8HwDFDBUEHZsDD5hbTFFFKZTSGWQJ1u6Cw61wnXaZ0hmCcoFe73a3F4-EI7ngMFCyBIEAY8DQ-BgJDAYFKMBOBORbyg7SUEBUUHUbg8uPxhOJpPJlLgNIgoGxAAFgjAALQ1DK7KWYAqYAA08AAREQCkU0i9kKV4BNnjUIuKVXTUUxQEA):

```js
class Foobar {
    public readonly value = 1;
    public readonly callback = () => {};

    public do() { }
}

 // TODO: this is the question
type ClassProperties<C extends new(...args: readonly unknown[]) => unknown> = object

const foobar = new Foobar()
const data: ClassProperties<typeof Foobar> = {...foobar}

data.value    // should be successful
data.callback // should be successful
// @ts-expect-error, "property does not exists"
data.do
```

Comment: could you share an example on how you would use this type and what result you are expecting?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @TobiasS. I've added one. It isn't a real-world example although, but the core point remains the same: I have a class, an instance of the class, I spread the instance with `{ ...instance }` and I need to describe the spread result in types.

Comment: This is not currently possible as per [ms/TS#9726](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9726).  You can make various simplifying assumptions (the easiest of which is to assume that classes never/rarely have function-valued instance properties), but anything you do here will be an approximation at best and have failure modes.  But... for any *specific* class like `Foobar`, the compiler already knows that spreading won't contain methods, like [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/Ndr1vW) shows. If you have a use case that requires you abstract this to the type level, can you actually show it?

Comment: (If you reply and want me to be notified, pls mention @jcalz in your comment)

Answer (score 1):

Oof that was hard, wrote over 400 LOC to solve that

Yes, you can differentiate between method and property, and ues, I'm going to submit it to [Type Challenges](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges) as Extreme so you can try: [Issue](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/issues/18708)

Solution

```
type A = { a: 1 }
type B = { b: 1 }

type fnMod<F extends (...args: any) => any> = (...a: ParMod<Parameters<F>>) => ReturnType<F>
type ParMod<P> = P extends [infer F, ...infer L] ? [F & B, ...L] : P

type IsMethod<T extends Record<string, (...args: any) => any>, K extends keyof T> = 
| {[k in K]: fnMod<T[k]>} extends Pick<T, K> ? 'method' : 'property'

type FPM = { p: (a: A) => void, m(a: A): void }

type z1 = IsMethod<FPM, 'm'> //  "method" 
type z2 = IsMethod<FPM, 'p'> // "property"
```

Comment: I don't see an explanation here for what you're doing, but presumably you're checking for parameter bivariance. That doesn't check for "own"-ness at all, which is what was asked.  Certainly the usual case is that methods are inherited and function-valued properties are not, so maybe that's a reasonable approach (but you should mention the distinction and the failure mode).  And even then, you can't test for bivariance if there are no parameters (what does `type FPM = { p: () => void, m(): void }` do?) or if the first parameter is of type `any` (`{ p: (a: any) => void, m(a: any): void }`?).

Comment: Could you [edit] to explain what you're doing and describe its limitations?

Comment: Very, very smart find! I'd love to see it explained (actually @jcalz's comment mostly covers that) and adapted to work with any class, as the OP asked. As a minor simplification, I'd recommend replacing the first argument type with `never` (or maybe all argument types) https://tsplay.dev/m0nMDw That takes care of the `any` argument case, while the argumentless case is still not covered

Comment: @kikon TIL `^?`, can you link me to docs? ("^?" is not properly googlable)

Comment: You can find it in the playground - help menu - "Twoslash annotations" (it doesn't seem to have a link)